# UTL_FILE Physical file location

Tags: plsql

I have oracle installed in my PC,I am executing a simple procedure to write a file using plsql(UTL_FILE),But i am unable to locate the physical file in corresponding directory even after successful execution of the procedure.

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

The file must exist in a Oracle Directory.
Then you must give the user write rights to this Oracle Directory. So that the user can use UTL_FILE to create a file in this directory.

For more information see: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5007.htm

Answer (score 0):

OS user should also have access on directory to read and write

Comment: Please provide a full answer. I understand that you are new and don't yet have privilege needed to comment on the other answer, but your answer needs to stand on its own.